# Fragment returns null while reading from sharedpreferences file

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, fragment-lifecycle

I am reading string value from sharedpreferences in fragment but it return null sometime? Here is my logcat output:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Home{fc6bf3a} (14420322-2dbf-46e9-9f52-12586f9fa36b) not attached to a context.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:900)
    at com.example.socialmediacloneapp.Fragments.Home.getUserName(Home.java:114)
    at com.example.socialmediacloneapp.Fragments.Home.access$000(Home.java:34)
    at com.example.socialmediacloneapp.Fragments.Home$1.onDataChange(Home.java:77)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
```

Here is my sharedPreference code:

```
 private void setUserName(String name){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("MyFile",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("name",name);

    editor.apply();

    b.textView.setText("Hi," + name);
}
```

How to avoid this exception while reading a value from sharedpreferences?

Answer (score 0):

call fun "setUserName" in to onViewCreated!